# Managing asp.net form with many fields

Tags: asp.net

I am using `asp.net/C#` ,, i have a form with many fields ,,, it is a registeration form of a bank ... currently i usd `css` to move and align fields on the form ...i didnot use the drag n drop feature .... My question is what would be the best way to manage such forms .. currently my form doesnot look organized... Should i use `absolute positioning` and align all my fields by dragging them .... Please suggest me the proper way of aligning and organizing such fields.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple semantic html - [validated](http://validator.w3.org/) of course
with css for styling is the recommended way.

Regarding absolute positioning or not - that depends.
There are lots of [example CSS Form sites](http://designshack.net/articles/10-css-form-examples), with [examples](http://www.duoh.com/csstutorials/cssform/index.html) and source code. I suggest you look there.

If you have a huge amount of fields you can break the page up into smaller pages (save each segment, allow back and next). If you are feeling brave you can use the Web Forms Wizard control - but I wouldn't personally as Web Forms has a way of turning on you.

Comment: +1 for warning him about the Wizard Control, I still have nightmares.